# ServiceStack: Explaination of the "Matching = ..." rules

Tags: servicestack, url-routing

I need an explanation of who the string inside the Matching = "..." rule is supposed to look.

I see only a few examples on docs.servicestack.com:

```
[Route("/users/{Id}", Matches = "**/{int}")]
[Route("/{UserId}/profile", Matches = @"{int}/**")]
[Route("/feed", Matches = "IsAuthenticated")]
```

and a few more.

I tried:

```
[Route("/myservice/bookings/{SearchString}", Matches = "**/{string}", Verbs = "GET")]
public class SearchAddress : IReturn<SearchAddressResponse>
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

but I got:

> : 'Unknown Matches Rule '**/{string}' in Route
>   '/myservice/bookings/{SearchString}''

I might add that this rule worked fine:

```
[Route(/myservice/bookings/{BookingId}", Matches = "**/{int}", Verbs = "GET")]
public class GetBooking: IReturn<GetBookingResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public uint BookingId { get; set; }
}
```

I have

```
/myservice/bookings/{SearchString} // a string to search for bookings
```

and

```
/myservice/bookings/{BookingId} // an Int for a specific booking
```

and I thought I could differentiate between them use the Matches rule. However, I'm not sure what rules I have to play with, or why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the docs on registering [Custom Matching Rules](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#custom-rules), if you’re not using a built-in rule you need to register the implementation in `Config.RequestRules`.

Comment: Ah, so the "**/{int}" and such is static, "hardcoded" strings that is directly translated according to that dictionary. I thought it was some kind of string that was interpreted depending on where u had the ** and such...